# In elisp, how can I get the buffer object that has specified name?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using `buffer-live-p` to test whether some buffer is live or not, but this function only accept the object of real buffer rather than buffer-name, so is there any easy way to get the buffer specified by the name or I can only achieve by looking up the buffer-list and testing each whether they have the given name?

Comment: FWIW, in many cases it's better to change the rest of the code so that you do have a buffer object to start with rather than only the name of a buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get-buffer`  ... apropos is your friend.

Comment: Thanks. Just feel that it is a bit difficult to get the accurate information when using apropos. For instance, when I use `buffer` as the keyword, the output is a 3750 line buffer:-( Is there any better way?

Comment: You're not restricted to getting documentation from within Emacs.  Googling "emacs buffer by name" gets you almost all the way there.

Comment: Thanks, @Sean. I guess I was using the wrong keyword when Googling.

Comment: @HongxuChen - Firstly, `apropos` searches by regex, so you can do something like `get.*?buffer` to narrow it down slightly. Second, you can do an incremental search on the buffer of results (by default with `C-s`).

Comment: @Inaimathi Personally I don't think this helps a lot since I might miss the right function when using `get .*?buffer`(how do you know there should be a `get` as the prefix beforehand?) Also, I do know there is such a key-binding for searching, but since I have filtered those unrelated symbols that doesn't contain `buffer`, that helps little(actually it outputs 3750 lines and I need to try `C-s` for about 400 times to get the function!) However I do hope there is a command called `apropos-function` or something like it so that I only need to look up for those function instead all symbols.